# SslStream - Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl

For a while, everything is fine, about 5 hours or more, everything works. But unexpectedly, when SslStream is authenticated using AuthenticateAsServerAsync (certificate, false, sslProtocol, true), I get the exception "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream." And no new socket can pass this authentication anymore. Only a complete server restart helps. What could be the problem?

Comment: You need to run from cmd.exe >Netstat -a on both client and server to see current state of the connection.  Is the channel idle when the connection is closed?  Some servers when a channel is idle will close connections.  Using a Keep-Alive will prevent the server from closing.  Keep-Alive with TCP periodically sends from client to server an empty packet so server doesn't close when channel is idle.

Comment: I watched through debugging that the listening socket was successfully accepting new connections (AcceptAsync), and then I would authenticate the new socket asynchronously. Probably, if the socket continues to listen, then it is alive. But authentication is already stopping.

Comment: The listener is application layer.  The TCP is transport layer.  So the TCP can be closed without the Listener closing.  You can only have one connection with the same 3 parameters 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port number.  So if the port wasn't closed properly you cannot make a new connection with same 3 parameters.  Netstat will give the status of the connection.  The Listener can still accept connections from other IP addresses while one connection was not closed properly.